# sqrt() の引数に変数をいれるとコンパイルエラーとなる。undefined reference。どうしたらいいでしょうか。

Tags: c, gcc

コメントアウトした文のように、直接的に数値を代入すると問題ありませんが、変数をいれるとコンパイルエラーが出てしまいます。
どうしたらいいでしょうか。

**実行環境:**
Ubuntu
gcc 9.3.0

**コンパイル結果:**

```
$ gcc sqrtyou.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc0MDw2q.o: in function `main':
sqrtyou.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**ソースコード:**

sqrtyou.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double first=2.0;
    double second;

    second=sqrt(first);
  //second=sqrt(2.0);

    printf("%f\n",second);
}
```

Comment: これが原因では？ [ライブラリのリンクを忘れずに](https://qiita.com/percipere/items/678a8ec1299a7564f6a3)

Comment: 直接的に数値を代入した場合に問題が発生しなかったのは、`sqrt()` が gcc のビルトイン関数に置き換えられてコンパイル時に計算されたためです。[Other Builtins (Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) なお、コンパイルオプションに `-O` を付ければ `sqrt(first)` でも同様の結果が得られます(`-lm` が不要になります)。

Answer (score 5):

コメントも付いていますが、 [sqrt() のマニュアル](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html)にも

> -lm でリンクする。

と説明されています。マニュアルを読むようにしましょう。